# Parse on iOS: Crash when linking PFUser to Facebook

Tags: facebook, ios7, parse-platform

I know this has been asked long ago on Parse.com forums (now closed): see https://www.parse.com/questions/getting-a-crash-on-trying-to-link-user-to-facebook

Yet no one seems to know why it doesn't work. It seems crazy that this function is in the documentation, causes a crash, and (conveniently) doesn't exist in any provided sample project.

```
if (![PFFacebookUtils isLinkedWithUser:user]) {
    [PFFacebookUtils linkUser:user permissions:nil block:^(BOOL succeeded, NSError *error) {
        if (succeeded) {
            NSLog(@"Woohoo, user logged in with Facebook!");
        }
    }];
}
```

Note: the linkUser function is the one that causes the crash. The user logged in and is definitely authenticated according to my NSLog.

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'User cannot be saved
>   unless they have been authenticated via logIn or signUp'
>   *** First throw call stack: (0x2d976f0b 0x38109ce7 0x2d976e4d 0xb78fb 0xa4a59 0x106421 0x385f2d53 0x385f8689 0x385f88dd 0x38723c17
>   0x38723adc) libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of
>   type NSException

Edit: Also note that linkUser never returns, so there is no way to handle the error.

Comment: What is the `user` you are passing to `linkUser`? The error is saying that `user` can't be any arbitrary user. It should be the one returned from login or sign up functions.

Comment: It is the current user i.e. [PFUser currentUser]

Comment: This error occurs when the user is not [PFUser currentUser]. You might wanna double check if your user is [PFUser current user] or not.